# How to find keep-alive config setting value for server?

Tags: bash, http

We are getting connection closed error from server and want to gracefully close connection on our client end, i want to set keep-alive timeout on our end, but is there a way i can know keep-alive value on server end ? ( any curl flag) so i can set my keep-alive value lower than server value.

Comment: I don't think so.

Comment: In general I'd expect it to be just a few seconds. You're only supposed to keep the connection open if you're making requests immediately after each other.

Comment: If the server is advertising something, it'll be in the headers. Ask for the headers (`curl -I`), see what's there -- if there's nothing there, it's not provided.

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Keep-Alive -- it's an _optional hint_. Servers are allowed to provide it, but they aren't obligated to.